# How does a child query it's parent's stepchildren in SOQL?

Tags: soql

I have a query for a record that I would like to include the parent and parent's children in.  It seems like this should work but it does not.  Is this possible to do in SOQL?

```
SELECT 
    Name
    Account_Name__r.Name,
    (SELECT 
         Filter__c 
     FROM
         Account_Name__r.Commerce_Product_Filters__r)
FROM 
Account_Var_Relationship__c
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not possible in a single query unless there are two distict "child" objects (self-relationship fields like `ParentId` on Account won't work, or at least not as easily), and they share a common parent.

In that case, you can simply make the outermost query to be on the common parent.

```
SELECT Name, 
    (
        SELECT 
            Name 
        FROM 
            Account_Var_Relationships__r
    ), 
    (
        SELECT 
            Filter__c 
        FROM 
            Commerce_Product_Filters__r
    ) 
FROM 
    Account
```

Comment: Please note this will count as 3 query so writing separately is same as writing in same

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty Not quite. It'll only count as a single query against the limit of 100 per synchronous transaction. Inner queries are counted as "aggregate queries" (which is perhaps a poor name, since it has nothing to do with Aggregate functions, and doesn't return an `AggregateResult`). The limit for aggregate queries per transaction is 300, so you could have 100 queries with 3 inner queries each, and still be fine. I do think, however, that the rows returned by inner queries are counted against the 50,000 row limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you need to have a direct relationship between object to get the data in soql. To achive the results in this manner you have to do multiple query.

You can get data of parent by quering child. You can go up to 5 lavel from child to parent, grand parent and great grand parent. There is no way to get siblings data.

Comment: The limit for traversing up a relationship hierarchy is actually 5 levels. See "Relationship query limits" in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm